# Can we have a single SO/SE for all languages, to have large community/data, to answer/identify questions, to attain any desired conformations?

Tags: feature-request, languages

Related: http://labs.theguardian.com/digital-language-divide/

Can we allow posts in any language, and auto translate them, or allow users to translate them, or leave them in original language, in which they might be posted?

Would this allow having large community, which would be knowing greater quantity of data, to identify/answer questions?

Edit: *On having users of all or most of the languages*

Can we allow users, on visiting SE, choose the language, say Chinese (as they seem to have most of internet users after English) to have all the headings as questions, home, in the chosen language? Then may be we can allow them post in their language, here chinese. If auto translator is not translating sentences as what is being expressed in other language, can we leave all the posts in their original language, i.e. can we have only headings in chosen language and leave all the user posted content in their original language? If we do this, would we have most of the Chinese users in SE, and would it be allowing them write Chinese answers to English questions (if they know meaning via (auto) translating English post?), etc.?

*On whether having all language speakers be allowing optimal attainment of thought conformations via Q&A or not*

1. Would having multiple language posts allow other language speakers get answers in other languages?
2. Would other language speakers be knowing “concepts” which non speakers be not knowing? Would this allow getting answers or questions which we may otherwise not know? Related: [1]
3. Would having greater no of users than on having only English speaking users, allow having optimal answers or optimal questions in attaining thought conformations?

[1]: Hecht, Brent, and Darren Gergle. "The tower of Babel meets web 2.0: user-generated content and its applications in a multilingual context." Proceedings of the SIGCHI conference on human factors in computing systems. 2010.

Comment: No auto-translation nowadays is good enough, unfortunately. Also there are some non-english variations of SO (such as Portuguese, Russian and Spanish).

Comment: And everyone that wants to read in a different language can use a translation tool/plug-in on their preferred browser

Comment: @Luuklag: I thought multiple languages would allow having large community (allowing speakers of all languages to be in a single site), with lot of data, which isolated language community seems to not have. Yeah, it seems that, say chinese, who need data, may translate it via translator himself, but......?

Comment: @Renan: Yeah, we seem to have SO in multiple languages; instead can we have a single SO or SE allowing users to post in any of the language? Would this allow having large community, and large data?

Comment: @Renan: If translators can‘t translate, as what sentences in other language would be saying, can we allow users to translate them as needed?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer _Can we allow_ doesn't really make a good feature request. Please state clearly what should be added as a feature (in technical or UI terms), and how and why you think this would add value to improve the SE sites.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Hi, I have edited question.

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer I've seen that. Not much improvement for a good FR so far. Mostly questions, not proposals or fact data.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to auto translate posts in most of other languages (at least Chinese, as it seems to have most of the users using internet after English), and to show them as auto translated and as original post?

No, I don't think it's worth to spent developer time to realize this.

Most auto translators (e.g. like browser plugins or google translate) are fairly good enough to give reasonable translations.

Also there's already a number of language specialized (SO) sites available:

- Russian: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
- Spanish: https://es.stackoverflow.com/
- Portugese: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/
- Japanese: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/

and a number of sites where it's allowed to use languages other than English:

- Russian: https://rus.stackexchange.com/
- Spanish: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/
- German: https://german.stackexchange.com/
- French: https://french.stackexchange.com/
- Portugese: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/
- Ukrainian: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/
- Italian: https://italian.stackexchange.com/
- Chinese: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/
- etc.

Comment: I think you misunderstood Renan's comment, which laments that current auto-translation tools are *not* good enough for the OP's suggestion.

Comment: Can we not allow, say Chinese (who seem to have lot many internet users after English), to post in SE or SO, and allow other users to answer in Chinese or any language; and allow users to translate it, if needed, in any language as needed, and give multiple versions of the post?

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer You are always free to propose a new site at Area51.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ since the "leaving" of Robert I would only redirect to Area 51 with a lot of "low hope" warnings ...

Comment: @PM2Ring sonce this answers suggesting using extensions or other tools rather than using dev time, I think it goes in the same spirit as my comment.